# MySQL Join Two Queries Horizontally

Tags: mysql

I have a query that works correctly to pull a series of targets and total hours worked for company A. I would like to run the exact same query for company B and join them on a common date, which happens to be grouped by week. My current query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT org, date,
         ( SELECT SUM( target ) FROM target WHERE org = "companyA" ) AS companyA_target,
         SUM( hours ) AS companyA_actual
  FROM time_management_system
  WHERE org = "companyA"
  GROUP BY WEEK( date )
  ORDER BY DATE
) q1

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT org, date,
         ( SELECT SUM( target ) FROM target WHERE org = "companyB" ) AS companyB_target,
         SUM( hours ) AS companyB_actual
  FROM time_management_system
  WHERE org = "companyB"
  GROUP BY WEEK( date )
  ORDER BY DATE
) q2 

ON q1.date = q2.date
```

The results show all of the dates / information of companyA, however companyB only shows sporadic data. Separately, the two queries will show the exact same set of dates, just with different information in the 'target' and 'actual' columns.

```
companyA    2012-01-28  105.00  39.00   NULL      NULL          NULL   NULL 
companyA    2012-02-05  105.00  15.00   NULL      NULL          NULL   NULL
companyA    2012-02-13  105.00  60.50   companyB  2012-02-13    97.50  117.50
```

Any idea why I'm not getting all the information for companyB?

As a side note, would anybody be able to point in the direction of converting each row's week value into a column? With companyA and companyB as the only two rows?

I appreciate all the help! Thanks.

Comment: Where's the date association in the target table.  I see the association on the org relationship, but nothing date-wise.  Without it, I see why company "A" as the same target on all 3 weeks.

Comment: Hi DRapp, the target column is correct in that it should be a comparison of the total target hours per week. The part that seems to be an issue is that Company B's information only appears sporadically. Note the null values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WITH no date apparent in the target table, the summation will be constant across all weeks.  So, I have performed a pre-query for only those "org" values of company A and B with a group by.  This will ensure only 1 record per "org" so you don't get a Cartesian result.

Then, I am querying the time_management_system ONCE for BOTH companies. Within the field computations, I am applying an IF() to test the company value and apply when correct.  The WEEK activity is the same for both in the final result, so I don't have to do separately and join.  This also prevents the need of having the date column appear twice.  I also don't need to explicitly add the org column names as the final column names reflect that.

```
SELECT
      WEEK( tms.date ) as GrpWeek,
      IF( tms.org = "companyA", TargetSum.CompTarget, 00000.00 )) as CompanyATarget,
      SUM( IF( tms.org = "companyA", tms.hours, 0000.00 )) as CompanyAHours,
      IF( tms.org = "companyB", TargetSum.CompTarget, 00000.00 )) as CompanyBTarget,
      SUM( IF( tms.org = "companyB", tms.hours, 000.00 )) as CompanyBHours
   from
      Time_Management_System tms
         JOIN ( select 
                      t.org,
                      SUM( t.target ) as CompTarget
                   from 
                      Target T
                   where
                      t.org in ( "companyA", "companyB" ) 
                   group by
                      t.org ) as TargetSums
            ON tms.org = TargetSums.org
   where 
      tms.org in ( "companyA", "companyB" )
   group by
      WEEK( tms.date )
   order by
      WEEK( tms.date )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see what you're doing and this looks like a great approach. I tried your code and it seems to add the two targets together in to the first target column. "companyA" and "companyB" have two different targets entered. Also, the CompanyB target and hours columns return empty. Any idea why that might be happening? I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Anjroo, my oops... forgot GROUP BY on innermost query generating the "TargetSums" results.  Try again

Comment: Great, we're much closer. I modified the first column just to verify the date against the data, and it appears that the range is beginning on separate days for each company. For example, companyA begins on 11/05, while copmanyB begins on 11/07. I've tried to add three lines of result below. Is there a way to unify the date range? Perhaps start from the very first entry, then select time entries that fall within that range?

    
`2011-11-05 105.00 4.50 0.00 0.00` 
`2011-11-07 0.00 8.00 97.50 100.00` 
`2011-11-14 0.00 2.75 97.50 98.25`

Comment: There was nothing indicating the "Week" start for a company.  Show table structure.  As for Week, WEEK is based on the calendar WEEK OF YEAR, not based on some fiscal year or calendar, such as starting on Monday for one company and Saturday for another.  It COULD be done, but they wouldn't line up on a common row basis... unless each row represented a week number and we just displayed the starting date OF that week.  Some extra work and can be, can you show an output of what you would expect for showing BOTH date versions per company in your output sample.

Comment: Ahh, week of year. Okay, that makes sense. I think I've got it working how I'd like now, thanks to your query structure. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Both of your subqueries are wrong.

Either you want this:

```
SELECT 
org,
WEEK(date),
( SELECT SUM( target ) FROM target WHERE org = "companyB" ) AS companyB_target,
SUM( hours ) AS companyB_actual
FROM time_management_system
WHERE org = "companyB"
GROUP BY WEEK( date )
```

Or else you want this:

```
SELECT 
org,
date,
( SELECT SUM( target ) FROM target WHERE org = "companyB" ) AS companyB_target,
SUM( hours ) AS companyB_actual
FROM time_management_system
WHERE org = "companyB"
GROUP BY date
```

The way you are doing it now is not correctly formed SQL. In pretty much any other database your query would fail immediately with an error. MySQL is more lax and runs the query but gives indeterminate results.

- [GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response! I just tried both of your queries with mine, but still seem to be having issues. Could you be a tad more explicit in what I should be looking at? Did you mean, replace my join sub-query with either one of the above? The first didn't return any results, while the second returned sporadic (but different) results. Thanks!

Comment: @Anjroo: "Did you mean, replace my join sub-query with either one of the above?" Yes - I'm guessing you mean the second one, and you need to fix BOTH your subqueries. But really only you know what you are trying to do. Your query  doesn't make sense in its current form - it's invalid SQL. Why are you grouping by `WEEK(date)` but then only selecting `date`? It really doesn't make any sense to me that you'd try to do that. Can you explain what you were thinking when you wrote it? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hmm, so my goal is to create a display of "hours entered" versus "target hours" for work that's been done. I'm grouping by week to get a sum of hours in a week across a number of months, as opposed to the individual entries, which could be multiple per day.

How should I go about making it valid SQL code? Thanks again.